# 80/20 rule expression (Pareto Principle)

Tags: expressions, yoji-jukugo

Is there a saying (ことわざ）or 4 character phrase (四字熟語) in Japanese for the 80-20 rule (i.e. the Pareto Principle)? i.e. it takes 20% of the effort to get 80% of the results but to get the last 20% of the results takes 80% of the effort.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is also known in English as the Pareto principle.

From this site https://takuminotie.com/blog/2015/09/09/post-9226/

we have the usage

> パレートの法則

The site also says that...

> それで、これらは俗に80対20の法則、2：8の法則、80-20ルールとも呼ばれる。

Comment: While it's helpful to know about the Pareto principle, I don't see if it answers the real question about kotowaza or 4-character phrase... Does it exist?

Comment: @AndrewT. I don't think that any of the constructions I have listed come close to being *kotowaza* or *yojijukugo*. Maybe I should say that in my answer, but I feel hesitant to state categorically that there is no *kotowaza* or *yojijukugo*.